# Markdown / alternative in Text() to set custom weight to inline text (bold or heavy)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to set the specific font weight with the "inline" Markdown specifiers (`**`)?

This code below displays `Days` with thin font weight, and `10` with bold*er* weight. It looks to me to display it with medium weight. I would like to display `Days` with medium weight, and `10` with bold or heavy weight.

```swift
Text("**10** Days")
    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .thin, design: .rounded))
```

Alternatively, is there another (easier / simpler) way to do this, other than creating multiple Text() views in an HStack, which I then have to manually edit the padding for, so it looks correctly inline?

Comment: You can utilize [`AttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) to fully customize them, but its much easier to just concat 2 separate `Text`s in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate `Text` objects using `+`, so maybe something like this would work for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            daysLabel(10)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
    }
    
    func daysLabel(_ days: Int) -> Text {
        Text("\(days)").bold() +
        Text(" Days").fontWeight(.thin)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Question was about markdown, not about making one string from multiple strings.

Comment: @VladimirSukanica The question explicitly states _"Alternatively, is there another (easier / simpler) way to do this, other than creating multiple Text() views in an HStack, which I then have to manually edit the padding for, so it looks correctly inline?"_

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `LocalizedStringKey`

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("**10** Days"))
    .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .thin, design: .rounded))
```